# Repeated measures analysis and autocorrelation

Tags: time-varying-covariate

Imagine 10 people.

In year 2016, the first 5 people have a response $Y$ measured on days randomly allocated throughout the months of January to July. The days were random **for each individual.**

In year 2017, the other 5 people were again measured on *different* individual-specific random days throughout the same period.

I have similar data for years 2015, 2014, .... etc, (involving 5 other people each time).

I want to analyse the response using regression, but my main issue is, how do I account for temporal autocorrelation?

In fact, my primary issue is, how do I even model the "time" variable?

What would you do?